# ASP.NET MVC : Not sure how to make these routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

i'm trying to make the following routes .. and currently i'm going about this in a *really* long way.. ie. one route instance for EACH route.

this is what i'm after...  (assuming i'm doing a 'stackoverflow website')

```
/                        <-- root site
/page/{page}             <-- root site, but to the page of questions.
/tag/{tag}/page/{page}   <-- as above, but the questions are filtered by tag
/question/ask            <-- this page :P
/question/{subject}      <-- reading about a question
```

(and no.. i'm most definitely not doing a stackoverflow website :)  )

cheers!

(gawd i find dis all so confusing at times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your third one, I'd do something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("page-tag", "tag/{tag}/page/{page}", new {controller="question", action="FilterByTag"});
```

Your action method then could look like this:

```
public class QuestionController : Controller {
  public ActionResult FilterByTag(string tag, int page) {
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: @Phil, if i use your page-tag route ... do i need to make a new route for /page or /tag?

alternatively ... should i be having seperate routes for these? or should they be querystrings instead because they are minor value-add actions to the main action (listing questions).

Comment: It's up to you. Both are valid approaches. Some people don't like query string parameters, but many of the reasons for that view are now defunct. Google does index query string parameters.

Comment: Phil, if you were going to have to do paging/sorting/filtering on a list of items (eg. 'questions' view, or 'products' view, etc), how would you do it? (post an example route/url to explain your answer). Please :)

Answer (score 0):

I would change the last url to /question/view/{subject}.
Futher Create 3 controllers:

- PageController
- TagController
- QuestionController

in Global.asax create those routes,(take example at the default route)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cheers for the comment.

I'm not after what controllers i need to make, just how to define the routes properly .. and how many routes.